# Redraw a chart after zooming [JFreeChart]

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am currently working on a XYChart that displays a signal (sinusoïds for example). I am currently able to display it really nicely, but I have a problem. I want to be able to display 10000 points per seconds, but the displaying part is getting really slow.

I was asking myself if it was possible to draw a "new" chart with the exact coordinates the user zoomed on. The more I zoom, the more points I will be able to place. The original zoom will get a number of points divided by the time elapsed.

Is there a zooming event that I can manipulate on a drag and drop zoom or a mouse wheel zoom ? And can I get informations about the number of pixels on the X Axis ?

Thanks, 
Proxy.

Comment: See also the approaches shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks, i'll give it a look !

Comment: You are welcome; a similar issue is examined [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117613).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod, added a chartChangedListener. When the user zooms in, the chart sets another Dataset to itself and then adds a new Listener. This causes the chart to redraw and then the more you zoom, the more points you get (thx to mathematics). Now, gotta search how to differentiate zoom in and zoom out, because zoom out is now dead.